# I need to push the array standard format

Tags: php, arrays

**Array**

```
Array (
    [0] => 1436073376-java_tutorial.pdf 
    [isread] => 0 
)
Array (
    [0] => 1436073294-hadoop_tutorial.pdf 
    [isread] => 0 
)
```

I need expected output like

```
Array (
    [0] => 1436073376-java_tutorial.pdf 
    [isread] => 0
),
Array (
    [1] => 1436073294-hadoop_tutorial.pdf 
    [isread] => 0 
)
```

what i have tried is

```
$filenameuploaded = array_push($1starray,$secondarry);
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense.  It is missing a closed parens, that might help.

Comment: yes sorry was that was typo mistake

Comment: do you really want to change num index in 2nd array from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: try using `array_merge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$array1 = array(
    '0' => '1436073376-java_tutorial.pdf',
    'isread' => 0
);
$array2 = array(
    '1' => '1436073294-hadoop_tutorial.pdf',
    'isread' => 0
);

$result[] = $array1;
$result[] = $array2;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```